# Where (place) to make a repository in a mac?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm on a Mac and I want to create a repository inside my HDD. I also want the other Desktop Windows PC's to connect to my repository.

Where would I create my repository that the other PC's can access it via IP(inside a local network)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general outline of what you need to do:

- Create a new user on your MAC (e.g. *svnadmin*).
- Create a directory for your repositories under `~svnadmin` (e.g. `~svnadmin/repos`).
- Create a new repository (say, `my_repo`) in `repos` with `svnadmin create` - [here is how](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html).
- Configure and start SVN server - [here's how](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html).

All the steps above should be done with `svnadmin` user.

You will now be able to access your repo with `svn://<you-mac-ip>/my_repo`.

Comment: It works over TCP/IP. So if your TCP/IP works over Wi-Fi - it will work over Wi-Fi.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I'm getting the response "No Repository found" after my svn import. I'm over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Can you access it from the Mac itself via `localhost`?